# Monitor internal network packets

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, wireshark

I have web service and client running on the same system. I would like to monitor packets cumming both ways while applications communicates between each other.

I'm plannig to use Wireshark for this purposes. But I have heard that it is not possible to monitor internal packets when both client and server are running on the same machine. And this is true - I don't see any internal packets. I was planning to solve this problem by running client on Vmware virtual machine that runs on Vmware workstation. But still cant get packets.

How to build such workaround system that could monitor packets between two application in one hardware PC?

Answer (score 2):

(You don’t have an operating system specified. I’ll assume you’re using Windows.)

Starting from Windows Vista, [you actually *can* capture loopback traffic](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback). What you want is [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/), an “upgrade” to WinPcap.

Make sure you tick the option to support loopback capture while installing.

After installing, you will have a new virtual network connection that represents the loopback connection. You can use it with Wireshark.

IIRC the adapter has no descriptive name by default (“Ethernet 2” or similar), so you might want to rename it.

Comment: npcap looks like a real gem of a project.

Answer (score 2):

vmnet-sniffer command that comes with VMWARE Workstation.

If your OS is Linux. You can use below command to Trace Packets

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmnet-sniffer -e -w mypackets.pcap /dev/vmnet8
```

Control + C (Stops theTrace)

Note: vmnet8 (It may Change. Its Depends on your Scenario)

You might be on vmnet1 if you are using host-only networks. Just give both a shot if you aren’t sure.